# If you do the right thing

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy

I have heard a lot of people say, if you do the right thing you will never lose out even in this world. Is there a source for this?

Comment: שלוחי מצוה אינן נזוקין?

Comment: Suppose someone passes up an opportunity to earn money dishonestly. Some might view that as losing out, but someone with bitachon would say that money was never meant for them in the first place, and they are better off without it.

Comment: True and one could argue that they will ultimately lose it as the SA rules that one who works on Tisha Ba'av, Purim or on Friday afternoon (MB OC 251:3 seems to rule that it means from Mincha Ketana not Mincha Gedola) will not see any gain from the profits incurred. However, how would we understand other things such as Jews over the ages who were tortured because they refused to convert to Christianity or Islam? Is the correct Hashkafa that they would have had a worse life if they would have converted? Or is the correct understanding that this rule only applies to Olam haba/The World to Come?